# Pinescript: get year of strategy.closedtrade

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I would like to know if it is possible in pinescript to get the buy year for every trade in strategy.closedtrades?

I tried to use **strategy.closedtrades.entry_time[num_trade]** but I was not able to get the year out of this Unix timestamp.

On the other hand I have tried to use
**year[strategy.closedtrades.entry_bar_index[num_trade]]**, but this raises an error because of to many used bars.

Any idea if this is possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `year()` function to get the year of a timestamp. For example:

```
year(strategy.closedtrades.entry_time(strategy.closedtrades - 1))
```

You can `loop` through the closed trades, and do the thing you want. For example:

```
for i = 0 to strategy.closedtrades - 1
    yearOfBuy = year(strategy.closedtrades.entry_time(i))
    if yearOfBuy == 2020
        do something
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this solution. Looks like it is to easy to find :).